# How do I post the first value of a query set in HTML?

Tags: python, html, django

Hey guys I need to post the first value of a query set in HTML. Currently, I'm iterating through the entire query site and printing out every match but I don't want that.  I'm using Django and I use the objects.get() filter which I thought only grabs one record but it is grabbing multiple.

I just want it to grab the category they were just in so after they make a post, they can easily return back to that categories forum page.

How do I print it out in HTML or how do I do the Django query to only get one record so I can easily just display that in HTML?

Thanks!
HTML:

```
{% for query in queries %}
   <h4>Return to the <a href="/movies">{{query.category}}</a> Forum</h4>
   {% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
query = NewPost.objects.get(category = category)
return render(request, "network/posted.html", {"queries": query})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questions seems confusing. Do you mean the first object of a queryset? If so, first() [doc about first()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#first) will work well.

```
first = YourModel.objects.all().first()

# or

first = YourModel.objects.filter(....).first()
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  I used .first() and then printed it in HTML {{using queries.category}}

Answer (score 0):

I used .first() and then printed it in HTML {{using queries.category}}